# How To Tell What Subscription a Visual Studio Azure Wep App Will Be Published To

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Given a VS web app project that has an existing Azure publish profile is there a way to tell what subscription the selected publish profile will publish the app to? We have such so many subscriptions it's quite time consuming to to use the portals poor blade interface to locate which subscription the app is in. Even opening the SCM site it seems apps know nothing about it's subscription.

Comment: sorry, is opening 2 blades time consuming? how so?

Comment: @4c74356b41 When you have many subscriptions and many resources and the only thing you can do is sort on Type or filter by name I find it quite painful. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, we don't need Azure subscription information to publish our project. What we need is contentPath, ComputerName, UserName& Password when you use msdeploy. The following is the parameters that used to deploy:

```html
.\msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath='E:\code' -dest:contentPath='sub2',ComputerName='https://waws-prod-sn1-047.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=sub2',UserName='$sub2',Password='key',AuthType='Basic'
```

If we published project to Azure, we have no easy way to see which subscription it belongs to. I suggest you submit a voice at [Azure feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Thanks, I figured subscription was not needed for deployment but it would have been nice if the kept it around when you actually selected it